# Hidding ip address in a peer to peer connection

Tags: javascript, ip

I'm curious is it possible to hide the ip address in a peer to peer connection. Mainly considering you have 2 computer connected remotly in a browser session. I would like to know if it's possible to hide the ip. 
Lets say `A` chats with `B` in a browser session chat build with Java script.  But i want that A not to be able to inspect the page and see B's ip, or donno network tool from chrome and vice versa. The idea is the user to be able to get in contact only if they agree both to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with a direct point-to-point connection. You'll need a central server. That way, each connected client only knows the server's IP address.

Comment: thank you. I knew about that option, was curious if there's a other.

Answer (score 1):

There's another option, but it wouldn't be really P2P. You could use 2 proxy servers between the connection:

Client1 <-> Proxy1 <-> Proxy2 <-> Client 2 
0.0.0.0.......1.1.1.1.......2.2.2.2.......3.3.3.3

The real remote connection in this case should be 1.1.1.1 <-> 2.2.2.2 and not 0.0.0.0 <-> 3.3.3.3.

Comment: ... how is this different than just _one_ server?  If both clients are trusting a third party (their proxy servers), why does it have to be **two** of them?  A single server would be vastly simpler to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

2 options here:

1) Client-Server model
2) Tor network model, where each client only knows the next "hop destination" for the message and not the final destination.